# Magento2: What's the right/best way to override the getProductsCollection() on category pages?

Tags: product-collection, magento2.2.3, override-model

My goal: I want to create a special category that will display products by different rules (not by associated products), for example: 'products on sale' / 'new products' / 'products from multiple categories', ...
I saw some extensions that overrided the ListProduct block but I think that it's a bad solution as it has no effect on the layered navigation for example.
I also prefer to use plugins instead of overriding the original classes in order to avoid conflicts as much as possible.
At the moment, I keep overriding more & more core classes & still face issues & I think I'm missing something.

---

-- Any idea?

Comment: why you don't create new category for [ 'products on sale' / 'new products'], this will be very good and you don't need to write any code, just assigning the right product to the right category. Please note that writing a code not always good idea if the magento standard can do the job

Comment: 1. That's what the client wants. 2. I want to know how to do that.

Comment: 3. While in cases when you have small amount of products it might be a good idea to just manage that manually, it can be very complicated when you have thousands of products.